# Bluetooth low energy sending command to iPhone app

Tags: ios, bluetooth, camera

I come across a problem. There is an iPhone app and also a BLE device. I'm not familiar with BLE, I just want to know if it is possible that sending a command with the device to the iPhone app to take a picture. Thanks advance!

Answer (score 0):

"Send a command" -- no

Generate an event which an observing application could respond to and take a picture, conceivably.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Presume I can respond to the event that comes from the device, is it possible that this event clicking the shutter instead of me? I don't know if I made myself clear.

Comment: You'd have to write an app that actually used AVFoundation to take the picture, and the device would almost certainly have to be on at the time, but yeah, it could be done.